# Deriving $\cosh \frac{x}{R} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- u^2 - v^2}}$ from $x = \frac{R}{2}\;\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}{1-\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\right)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Let
$$x = \frac{R}{2}\;\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}{1 - \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\right)$$
from which I derived that
$$\tanh \frac{x}{R} = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$$
I have difficulty somehow in deriving the formula
$$\cosh \frac{x}{R} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- u^2 - v^2}}$$
Any hints?

Comment: Knowing $\tanh$, you can find $\operatorname{sech}$, and then $\cosh$.

Comment: $1-\tanh^2(u)=\frac 1{\cosh^2(u)}$

Comment: Right, thank you very much